# Base64 - Exif metadata

Tags: image-processing, base64, exif

Is it possible to add EXIF metadata for "ImageDescription" to a base64 JPG image string? 
Could this one have a EXIF data "ImageDescription" that claims it's the *Stack Overflow* logo? http://pastebin.com/0vUsybJQ

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could add EXIF metadata by reading the text format jpg image, adding the metadata to the image in memory, then saving it again in the base 64 text format.

Comment: Here's a forum post on reading base64 images:  http://forums.asp.net/t/896621.aspx/1

Here's some info on reading and writing EXIF metadata: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Basically I was wondering if it's possbile to paste a base64 EXIF metadata string into a JPG base64 image string.

Comment: That wouldn't work because some of the time you would need to change some offsets, and (I think) you would need to change the remainder of the base64 image string if your pasted string didn't begin or end on a base64 character boundary.